# xamarin google drive images

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I am new in xamarin. I want to display images from google drive in xaml view. For that I have installed Google.Apis.Drive.v3 nuget package. Below is my code.

**C# CODE**

```
 **DriveService** driveService = new **DriveService**();
    var request = driveService.Files.List();
    request.Q = "mimeType='image/jpeg'";
    request.OauthToken = account.Properties["access_token"];
    request.Fields = "nextPageToken,files(id, name, thumbnailLink, webViewLink)";
    request.PageToken = pageToken;
    request.PageSize = 20;
    var result = request.Execute();
    var DrivePhotos = new ObservableCollection<object>(result.Files);
```

**XAML CODE**

```
<StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
                <flv:FlowListView FlowColumnCount="3" RowHeight="100" SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                          HasUnevenRows="False" FlowItemsSource="{Binding DrivePhotos}" >
                    <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackLayout Margin="3">
                                <!--<Image Source="{Binding thumbnailLink}" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Aqua" />-->
                                <!--<Label Text="{Binding name}"></Label>-->

                                <ffimageloading:CachedImage HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Accent" 
                                            WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300"
                                            DownsampleToViewSize="true"
                                            Source="{Binding thumbnailLink}">
                                </ffimageloading:CachedImage>


                            </StackLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                </flv:FlowListView>
            </StackLayout>
```

I am getting these fields in return id, name, thumbnailLink, webViewLink.

Now I am not able to display thumbnailLink in xmal  tag. I also using DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.FlowListView for displaying images.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNE3D.png)

Please help.

Comment: An  ObservableCollection<object> does not have any bindable properties.   You need to create a class that models the object returned from Google with the necessary public properties

Comment: Thanks @Jason. It worked. I was not converting google api response to bind able object.